# Why would non-recursion method takes more time than recursion?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

Take quick sort as an example, both recursion and non-recursion methods are listed below.

I think both methods actually implement the same algorithm, as a `stack` is used to simulate the recursion process in non-recursion method.

However, I got AC with recursion method but *Time Limit Exceeded* with non-recursion method after 85% test cases passed.

So, any problem with my non-recursion method or there is a time complexity difference between two methods?

THX!

```
// non-recursion
void sortIntegers(vector<int> &A) {
    if (A.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    stack<pair<int, int>> ranges;
    ranges.push(pair<int, int>(0, A.size() - 1));
    while (!ranges.empty()) {
        pair<int, int> r = ranges.top();
        ranges.pop();
        int mid = A[r.second],
            left = r.first,
            right = r.second - 1;
        if (r.first >= r.second) {
            continue;
        }
        while (left < right) {
            while (A[left] < mid && left < right) {
                left++;
            }
            while (A[right] >= mid && left < right) {
                right--;
            }
            swap(A[left], A[right]);
        }
        if (A[left] < A[r.second]) {
            left++;
        } else {
            swap(A[left], A[r.second]);
        }
        ranges.push(pair<int, int>(0, left - 1));
        ranges.push(pair<int, int>(left + 1, r.second));
    }

// recursion
void sortIntegers(vector<int> &A) {
    quick(A, 0, A.size() - 1);
}
void quick(vector<int> & A, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        return;
    }
    int mid = A[end],  //5
        left = start,  // 0
        right = end - 1;  //3
    while (left < right) {
        while (A[left] < mid && left < right) {
            left++;
        }
        while (A[right] >= mid && left < right) {
            right--;
        }
        swap(A[left], A[right]);
    }
    if (A[left] >= A[end]) {
        swap(A[left], A[end]);
    }else {
        left++;
    }
    quick(A, start, left - 1);
    quick(A, left + 1, end);
}
```

Comment: Function calls are used a lot, so likely very well optimized by the compiler. For example, the parameters might be passed in registers and not stored to memory like in the explicit stack.

Comment: Your `sortIntegers` function accesses items out-of-bounds on this line: `int mid = A[r.second]`.  Please [see this version of your function using `vector::at()`](https://www.ideone.com/lS1bZS).  Thus you cannot determine if something is fast or slow if your function introduces undefined behavior.  Fix your non-recursive function first, then rerun your results.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, you have at the bottom of your loop:

```
    ranges.push(pair<int, int>(0, left - 1));
    ranges.push(pair<int, int>(left + 1, r.second));
```

To me that should be

```
    ranges.push(pair<int, int>(r.first, left - 1));
    ranges.push(pair<int, int>(left + 1, r.second));
```

Comment: So, what is your explanation _why_ it should be that way?

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius It's quick sort.  With quick sort, you iteratively work with smaller and smaller regions of the original array.  The code as is means that half of all regions start with zero.  That's wrong, that's not how quick sort works.  With quick sort, you have a region from a to b, and you take a midpoint, and then you work with a to midpoint and with midpoint to b.  In second iteration, 1 of 2 regions start with 0.  In next iteration, 1 of 4 regions start with 0.  In next iteration, 1 of 8 regions start with 0.

Comment: @SeanF You missed the point of my comment. Currently the answer looks like "I prefer this sort of code, instead of that one", without any explanations as to why one is better than the other. Such an answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius you missed the point.  Quick sort is an established algorithm.  It's not a matter of preference, it's a matter of whether the code he wrote is right or wrong.  This is not a case of one piece of code being better.  This is a case of his code being incorrect.  It's not my job to explain quick sort to people, that goes way beyond reasonable to expect answers to explain concepts of computer science.  His question was that he wanted to write quick sort, and that something was wrong in his code.  My answer was to point out what was wrong in his code for it to be quick sort.

Comment: @SeanF You missed the point, once again; and you should stop putting your words, into the mouth of someone else: 1) I didn't say that it's a matter of preference. In fact, **your** statement "_**To me** that should be_" implies that it is. Which I already stated. 2) Where did I say that you should explain what quick sort is? I said that you should explain why one code snippet works, as opposed to the other. I.e. where the mistake was. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: You might write something like: There is a mismatch between correct `quick(A, start, left - 1);
    quick(A, left + 1, end);` and incorrect `ranges.push(pair<int, int>(0, left - 1));
    ranges.push(pair<int, int>(left + 1, r.second));`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Answer it yourself, don't dictate to others how to speak.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius You never give up whining, do you?  Yes, you did say it was a matter of preference, you said, and I quote: the answer looks like "I prefer this sort of code"  So yes, you said my answer was a matter of preference, that is exactly and precisely what you said.  Prefer = preference.   It's the same word.  No, the word "should" does not mean preference.  The word "should" is not about preference, it's about correctness.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius  Perhaps you are not a native English speaker.  That's fine. Well I am.   The expression "To me" is an expression of politeness.  Politeness is a quality sorely lacking around here.  The expression "to me" means that I am not 100% perfect nor 100% right, and that I can be wrong once in a while, unlike such god-like omnipotent know-it-alls like you and your new friend Jarod42.  It's an expression of civility and politeness.  It's a way of telling someone they are wrong without being nasty about it.  Try it out sometime.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Look up the word "should".  Here's Webster.  It means "used in auxiliary function to express a request in a polite manner or to soften direct statement".  It also means "used in auxiliary function to express obligation, propriety, or expediency".  In other words, it's telling someone they are wrong but being nice about it.  Got it?

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Now I've given zhaokai an answer that he was pretty darn happy about, and it's so darn direct and to the point it's easy for anyone to understand in a simple glance.  But I added a couple of words to make it polite.  On top of that, I've given you an English lesson.  You're welcome.

Comment: @SeanF 1) SO is meant to be a platform, which can be used in future research. Because of that, giving an answer that only OP is happy about - is not good enough, and was basis for my initial comment. 2) There are more non-native speakers of English, than native speakers, so if such an expression is, truly, understood only by native speakers (even though, I communicate with native English speakers, daily, and never heard such an expression used in the manner you proposed), you would still, be misunderstood most of the time.

Comment: @SeanF  3) I gave you suggestion (based on the reason I gave you in (1)). You went emotional about it. Am I the one, that's whining?